# What does the 'signatory' keyword means in daml representation?

Tags: daml

In a DAML contract, what does the `signatory` keyword do? For example, in the Iou contract, what does the line `signatory issuer, owner` actually mean?

Does it mean both owner and issuer should be same?

Answer (score 0):

One of the compelling features of DAML as a modeling language is that it is designed to help solve problems involving authorization and delegation. To achieve this DAML has a first class type `Party` that represents independent ledger participants, **and** every contract on the ledger must be *authorized* by one or more parties before it can be created.

The `signatory` expression in a template defines who must authorize the creation of a contract instance of this template. It does so in terms of the data contained within the proposed contract instance — this means that any party who can see a transaction that attempts to create a contract also has enough data to verify the creation was properly authorized.

In the case of the Iou contract:

```
template Iou
  with
    issuer : Party
    owner : Party
    currency : Text
    amount : Decimal
    observers : [Party]
  where
    signatory issuer, owner
  ...
```

A party wishing to create an Iou must fill in the record: `issuer`, `owner`, `currency`, etc. Then they must pass that record to the `create` function within a transaction submitted to the ledger. That call to `create` must be authorized by `issuer` and `owner`, but does not require authorization by `observers` as they are not listed as a signatory.

Note that it is legal for `issuer` and `owner` to be the same party. In fact, this would be the only way for the `create` to be legally submitted directly to the ledger as individual ledger interactions can only be authorized by a single party. Larger authorization sets must occur as a part of a larger transaction using delegated authority from other contracts already on the ledger.

For more on this, and especially on how to do authority delegation, see the DAML documentation: https://docs.daml.com/concepts/ledger-model/ledger-structure.html

For a worked example, see: https://docs.daml.com/daml/patterns/initaccept.html and the other examples in the *Patterns* section of the DAML docs.